# Create Dynamo db stream and trigger to trigger lambda using sam

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, sam

I am trying to create a lambda function using AWS SAM. This lambda should get triggered only when a Dynamo db column - say status = completed. Dynamo is already created manually outside SAM. Is there a way to create a stream, add this to lambda function as trigger along with filter policy using SAM.